# Restrict Feature Info fetched with the WMS GetFeatureInfo request with GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wms, openlayers-2, popup, getfeatureinfo

I followed a GeoEXT example to create a popup menu that gets WMS GetFeatureInfo on click on the map. What I want to do is to get some specific fields not all the fields; I tried the propertyName (with name1,name2 and name3) and defined the wanted fields but it doesn't work.  I also want to change the title by bringing a specific value not the fid, but it doesn't work, here's the code:

```
 feature Control, a "button" control
    action = new GeoExt.Action({
    control: new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
    autoActivate: true,
    infoFormat: "application/vnd.ogc.gml",
    maxFeatures: 6,
    layers: [layers1],
    propertyName: "name1,name2,name3",  
    eventListeners: {
    "getfeatureinfo": function(e) {
        var items = [];
        Ext.each(e.features, function(feature) {    
            items.push({
               xtype: "propertygrid",
               title: feature.fid, // here I changed it to feature.name1 it doesn't work
               source: feature.attributes               
            });
        });
        new GeoExt.Popup({
            title: "infos",
            width: 250,
            height: 300,
            layout: "accordion",
            map: map,
            location: e.xy,
            items: items
        }).show();
      }
    }
   }),
    map: map,
    text: "infos",
    tooltip: "Infos "
      });
    actions["infos"] = action;
    toolbarItems.push(action);
    toolbarItems.push("-");
```

Comment: Try "feature.attributes.name1"

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
propertyName: "name1,name2,name3",
```

with:

```
vendorParams: {
                propertyName: "name1"
            }
```